# Safari - How to search on a web page from the current selection onwards

Tags: macos, safari

Most browsers like Google Chrome and Firefox will search a we page from the current selection onward. It seems Safari does not support this.

Instead it searches from the beginning of the webpage.

How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily search from the point of selection using the following approach.

Immediately after selecting the string to search, use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to **record** the search string into find buffer.

Now press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to search from the selection point in the forward direction. To search backward, use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.

This works in most other apps apart from Safari.

Comment: This cannot be useful for my case, since I don't want to travel the whole page to select the string to search. This would take a lot of time.